# Why is Windows 10 logging off at random?

Tags: windows-10

I have this Windows 10 machine at work.  At the end of the day, I usually leave all programs running.  Typically these programs would be File Explorer, IBM RAD (IBM's version of Eclipse), Office programs such as Word, Outlook, Chrome browser etc.  I simply lock the machine.

Every now and then (once every 2-3 days) when I come in in the morning,  I see when I login all my running programs are gone.  When I go to Task manager and see if the machine rebooted, I see that it says the machine has been up for a several days.  So the machine has not rebooted.

That raises the possibility that I was somehow logged out.  One thing I note is that my default browser setting (which I set to Chrome) is gone and I have to set it again.

I am not familiar with Windows policies, which are managed by our administrative group.  This is also happening to another colleague of mine. Any idea why this might be happening?  Is there some way for me to debug this?

Note: Actually, when I am signing out, I am losing my default browser setting.  So Windows 1O is logging me out.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely group policy & you likely cannot override by design. Open cmd & enter `rsop` ([Result Set Of [group] Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772175(v=ws.11))) & poke around to see whats been configured. Although you may not be able to see all setting per design/security, notably the 'Computer Configuration' ones. If you were really desperate you could confirm the settings in the registry (see at links I provided below or seen in 'group policy settings reference' files from Microsoft). I'm quite sure there is a setting for inactive logoff time, default browser, etc. Best thing you can do is set you apps to open at login (right-click Win/Start button, Run, shell:startup [opens `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`]), you could maybe create a script to set your default browser to Chrome.

Relevant group policy settings:

- [User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Logon Options\Set action to take when logon hours expire](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2809) ([link 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-force-logoff-when-logon-hours-expire))
- [Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer\Set a default associations configuration file](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#10655) ([link 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/set-the-default-browser-using-group-policy))

`wmic os get LastBootUpTime` (run in cmd) will get actual bootup time as I believe if [fast startup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation) is that Task Manager 'Up time' could be off as a reboot doesn't actually do a full reboot, but that doesn't change your core concern.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try what you have suggested

Comment: Be sure to upvote helpful answers, which you can do to many. When you're ready you can 'accept' what you believe to be the best answer